# Re-open a case when a new chatter reply comes in?

Tags: chatter, case

I can already re-open a case if a new email comes in, but is there a way to re-open a case if a new Chatter reply comes in?

Comment: how are you re-opening a case?

Comment: You mean when someone added  reply to feedItem/Feed comment related to a Case?

Comment: @JDoe Yes. Exactly.

Comment: You need two automation 1) Trigger on the FeedComment object and 2) A Process Builder on the FeedItem object to identify if it is related to a case if yes, then open the case status. Let me if it make any sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger on FeedItem to open a case when a new open in made

```
trigger OpenCase on FeedItem (before insert) {
    List<Case> myCase = new List<case>();
    for (FeedItem f :trigger.new){
        if (f.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType) {
            Case c = new Case();
            c.id= f.parentid;
            c.Status='Open';
            myCase.add(c);
        }
    }
    If (myCase.size()>0){
        database.update (myCase,false);
    }
}
```

Apex trigger on FeedComment object to open a case

```
trigger OpenCaseComment on FeedComment (before insert) {
    List<Case> myCase = new List<case>();
    for (FeedComment fc :trigger.new){
        if (fc.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType) {
            Case c = new Case();
            c.id= fc.parentid;
            c.Status='Open';
            myCase.add(c);
        }
    }
    If (myCase.size()>0){
        database.update (myCase,false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm currently refreshes my sandbox. Will try this out ASAP.

Comment: Let me know how it goes

Comment: That worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to know! Cheers